# How did ILM create the hyperspace tunnel effect?

Tags: editing, filming, special-effects

In *Star Wars: **A New Hope***, right **before** the Millennium Falcon exits hyperspace, we see a "tunnel" through which the ship is traveling:

[image: The Millennium Falcon in hyperspace]

How did ILM create this effect in 1976?

---

**NOTE:** I am *not* referring to the "*stretching star lines*" effect shown when a ship enters or exits hyperspace as detailed by John Dykstra in a [1978 interview with the Fantasy Film Journal](https://ia800606.us.archive.org/11/items/Fantasy_Film_Journal_01_Winter_1977-78/Fantasy_Film_Journal_01_Winter_1977-78.pdf#page=11). I am specifically referring to the [blue tunnel](https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGp_5gOww0E?start=0&end=3) effect seen while the ship is still in hyperspace.

Comment: Nice question. However, the quality of the gif is hell. Can you provide one frame in *good quality* at least?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this method was used in this particular shot, but you might wanna have a look at the slit-scan method https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slit-scan_photography

Answer (score 3):

Although it looks like a slit-scan effect similar to the Tom Baker era Dr. Who titles, in this case, the effect was very simply made with mylar - a reflective plastic.  Due to time and budget constraints, there wasn't much they could do, so they made a tunnel out of mylar and flew the camera through it.  They apparently had a lot of mylar left from making the reflective background behind the starfield.

Comment: Welcome! Paraphrasing: surplus is the parent of special effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! If you update it with a source, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.